# Is there a way to do a global find/replace on ASP & HTML server IIS7

Tags: html, iis-7, asp-classic, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm running a IIS7 server on Windows 2008 R2 server.  The situation is that I sold a domain name.  I set up a new domain name, I did a global find/replace on all the files on the server and in all the records of the database to change all links and references from the sold domain name to the new domain name.  But I'm thinking of the few that I may have missed.  I'm wondering if there is a way I can catch these on the server level when the pages are served ... that would test each page and do a replace if the old domain name exists.  Maybe on the ASP (classic) parser and/or HTML server.

TIA,

Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how to do that using IIS but you could certainly use a find/replace on all files in the folder structure. Shouldn't be too bad on the sql side either. Once you figure it out I would highly recommend you don't include the domain name in your code. What you are fighting is exactly why using relative pathing is so much easier.

Comment: Actually they are links to an external site.  Since I own the server hosting many of my client's website, I have links to this particular domain name in many of their websites.  I need to change them all.  What I did was download notepad++ which had a global find/replace function that would do a find/replace in all files in a directory.  It took a while to run, but it is done.  For the SQL Server it was just a stored procedure that search all the column in all tables.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense about the external links. Yes notepad++ is a great tool for this sort of thing. Glad you found a solution.